# Flask-WTF custom validation FileField on picture pixel size

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make a custom validation on a FileField (Flask-WTforms). With the file field, I upload an image file and I want to check if the pixel size of the image is not too small. But with the validation, I get a 500 error response. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Below the code:

```
# forms.py #

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
from utils import check_picture_size

class GuideForm(FlaskForm):
header_img = FileField('Header Image', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
submit = SubmitField('Submit')

def validate_header_img(flaskform, field):
    check = check_picture_size(field.data)
    print(field.data) #Prints correct file <FileStorage: 'test.jpg' ('image/jpeg')
    if check:
        print('Check') #Prints 'Check' so it is True
        raise ValidationError("Uploaded picture is too small") # so is here something wrong???

# utils.py #

from PIL import Image

def check_picture_size(form_header_picture):
    i = Image.open(form_header_picture)
    if (i.size[0] < 1750) or (i.size[1] < 1000):
        return True
```

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: @Quentin The only error message is Internal Server Error - error in the application. Can't find the log files for Flask in the virtual environment, so I'm unable to provide more information at the moment.

Comment: Hm, that'd be helpful. Are you running this locally or on a cloud machine?

Usually, the internal server error messages are far more verbose.

Comment: Okay, I'm stupid. I overlooked a piece of code that abort the operation within the process of crop and save the image. When you said that mostly error messages are far more verbose got me thinking. You pointed me in the right direction!